# Join with second table based on first table column

Tags: mysql

hi i want to join my `registry_ug` table with a second table based on `registry_ug.type`.... i want to avoid the unnecessary join .

here is my code

```
   SELECT  ug.id , tbl.id FROM registry_ug ug
      JOIN    CASE ug.type 
             WHEN 1   THEN  users 
             WHEN 2   THEN  group_software 
       END
       AS  tbl
       ON 
       ug.id = tbl.id 

     WHERE ug.id = $uid
```

it seems ok to me but i get this error

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CASE ug.type WHEN 1 THEN users WHEN 2 THEN g' at line 2

SELECT ug.id , tbl.id FROM registry_ug ug JOIN CASE ug.type WHEN 1 THEN users WHEN 2 THEN group_software END AS tbl ON ug.id = tbl.id WHERE ug.id = 55
```

**and i dont want to join it to all of possible second tables **

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this this way. You can't use `CASE` expression this way. Try this instead:

```
SELECT  
  ug.id, 
  COALESCE(u.id, g.id)
FROM registry_ug AS ug
LEFT JOIN users          AS u ON ug.id = u.id AND ug.type = 1
LEFT JOIN group_software AS g ON ug.id = g.id AND ug.type = 2
WHERE ug.id = $uid
```

Comment: thanx but wouldn't this cuz unnecessary search in one of those tables ?i mean i want to join it to one of those this way it would join/search with both

Comment: @max you cannot use a `CASE` to join on different tables, you have to join on them.

Comment: how about IF  ? or it's unavoidable ? you now it's actually 4 tables and they are going to be pretty big

Comment: @max The two joins are unavoidable, but you can use the `IF` or `CASE` expressions instead of `COALESCE`. Feel free to edit your question and show these four tables.

Comment: thanx all the tables have the same columns and structure , i just wanted to avoid 3 extra expensive joins .

Answer (score 0):

give this a try,

```
SELECT  ug.id , 
        CASE WHEN ug.type = 1 
            THEN b.id 
            ELSE c.id
        END newID
FROM    registry_ug ug
        LEFT JOIN   users b
            ON ug.id = b.id 
        LEFT JOIN   group_software c
            ON ug.id = c.id 
WHERE   ug.id = $uid
```

*can't test, no sample data added*